# Get null when trying to retrieve datasource from FormRun

Tags: axapta, x++

I have 2 forms, let's call form A and B.
In form A, I have a button (blank button), when that button is clicked it will redirect to form B with parameters and that parameter will be inject to a datasource of form B. I failed to retrieve datasource of form B, it always returns null.

```
[FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(htVehicleListPage, FormCommandButtonControl1), FormControlEventType::Clicked)]
    public static void FormCommandButtonControl1_OnClicked(FormControl sender, FormControlEventArgs e)
    {
        FormDataSource htVehicleTable= sender.formRun().dataSource(formDataSourceStr(htVehicleListPage,htVehicleTable));
        htVehicleTable record=htVehicleTable.cursor();
        info(int2Str(record.htVehicleID)); //result: some legit ID.
        Args argsObj=new Args();
        argsObj.name(formStr(htVehicleMaintenanceDetails));
        FormRun formRunObj=new FormRun(argsObj);
        FormDataSource openningFormDataSource =formRunObj.dataSource(formDataSourceStr(htVehicleMaintenanceDetails,htVehicleMaintenance)); //result: openningFormDataSource is null, however, formRunObj is not null.
        Query queryObj=new Query();
        openningFormDataSource.query(queryObj);
        QueryBuildDataSource queryBuildDataSourceObj=queryObj.addDataSource(tableNum(htVehicleMaintenance));
        queryBuildDataSourceObj.addRange(fieldNum(htVehicleMaintenance,htVehicleID)).value(strFmt("htVehicleMaintenance.htVehicleID=%1",record.htVehicleID));
        formRunObj.init();
        formRunObj.run(); //if we inorge the null error it will show a form here
        formRunObj.wait();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FormRun` is just that...it's the running form object. Your `openningFormDataSource` will be null simply because you call it before `formRunObj.init();` and the form isn't running yet.

It goes `Form.init()`, then it does `Form...Datasource.init()`, then `Form.run()` basically.

Move your `formRunObj.init()` higher and try again.